# Ruby on Rails Fixtures in sub-directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails unit testing and fixtures framework. Unless there's a configuration I haven't seen, I can't use the "Advanced Fixtures" (no id objects) from fixtures in sub-directories:

fixtures/people.yml

```
_fixture:
  model_class: Person

myself:
  first_name: Me
  last_name: Myself
```

The following call will pass as expected:

```
fixtures :people
assert(people(:myself)))
```

while this one will not (after I move people.yml to subdir):

```
fixtures "subdir/people"
assert(people(:myself)))
```

In the later case, the error I get is this:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `people'
```

Using Advanced Fixtures seem valuable but having all of my fixture files in the root of /fixtures seems missing something. I have a few test files and I'd like to have various tests use different fixtures directories.

Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try saving people.yml in /fixtures/subdir/people.yml.  The documentation is here https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/TestFixtures/ClassMethods/set_fixture_class .

```
test_helper.rb

set_fixture_class :people => 'Subdir::People'

in your test file.

before do
  myself = subdir_people(:myself)
  register(myself)
end
it "should test myself" do 
  assert(people(:myself)))
end
```

Comment: That method subdir_people, where is it from? Is it there some automatic binding for it? Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Thanks for the update.   set_fixture_class "subdir/people" => Person, the class name should not be quoted, per the documentation. This is equivalent as setting the model_name in the YML. subdir_people() would be super convenient but it's not a defined method.

Comment: I don't think it's "before", rather in test cases it's "setup" ain't it?

Comment: Sorry.  I mix up things with rspec.  Have any luck with setup?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help, really. See my final setup above.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my final solution:

In the fixture file, I kept:

```
_fixture:
  model_class: Person
```

In the test file, I got:

```
  def people(sym)
    subdir_people(sym)
  end

  def test_myself
    assert(people(:myself))
  end
```

That way, it saves me from refactoring my numerous people() calls. Or I can use subdir_people() if I want.